# Rerun failed tests using NUnit commandline

Tags: c#, command-line, nunit, nunit-console

Is there a way to rerun the failed test of a test suite using NUnit from commandline. I know NUnit GUI support this. Is there something similar exists for commandline?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to this post
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nunit-discuss/GoB8R1Vze-4, the only way you can do this is by specifying the names manually.

Nothing like this can be found in the documentation of NUnit as well.

The v3 release let's you safe the results as an .xml file. Maybe in this release you can filter them out in a programmatic way and restart the failed tests
See https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/Console-Runner for more info